# Time string to total minutes integer in PHP

Tags: php

Simple question, but can't find it elsewhere:

How can I transform my string of time e.g. `"09:30"` into in integer containing the total minutes in that time? (Solution for `"09:30"` would be `570`)

I have tried a lot of stuff, including `substr`, `mktime` and `strtottime` and just can't get it to work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$time = explode(":","09:30");
$minutes = intval($time[0])*60 + intval($time[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference, strtotime works as well and it may be a simpler solution.

```
$minutes = strtotime('09:30', 0) / 60;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to explode the time string (something like: `explode(":","09:30")`). You can also use `str_replace`. Then just simply multiply the `09` with 60 and add the `30` to it.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, but thats mostly what I did, my error came in with not using `intval` I think.

Comment: No probs, Good luck with further scripting :)